# Bash: enumerate all the attached devices

Tags: android, bash, awk

I plugged several android devices to my laptop. And I can list their SN by

`adb devices`

output:

```
List of devices attached 
015d4a826e0ffb0f    device
015d4a826e43fb16    device
015d41d830240b11    device
015d2578a7280b02    device
```

I want to perform some operations on every device, like

`adb -s $device install foo.apk`

But I don't know how to let variable `device` iterate all the devices obtained by `adb devices`.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it in `bash`. Read the output of your command and iterate it on the second column using a `while loop`.

```
while read sn device; do
    adb -s "$sn" install foo.apk
done < <(adb devices | sed '1d')
```

Comment: This would try to install apk on devices: "of, attached, device, device, device...." TC need serial (first column) and all, but first line (List of devices attached)

Comment: I never worked with `adb` so was not sure if that was an actual output of if OP added it for clarity. I updated the answer to remove the first line before feeding the `while loop`. Thanks for your feedback! :)

Comment: OP also needs `$sn`, not `$device`, but main idea is correct, of course ;-))

Answer (score 3):

Main trick is to separate serial of device from other output. You need to cut off header and second column. Something like this would work:

```
for DEVICE in `adb devices | grep -v "List" | awk '{print $1}'`
do 
  adb -s $DEVICE install foo.apk
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `xargs` and `awk`:

```
adb devices | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I% adb -s % install foo.apk
```

**Demo:**

I put your input into a `file` and using `echo` to check the ouput produces:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print $1}' file | xargs -n1 -I% echo adb -s % install foo.apk
adb -s 015d4a826e0ffb0f install foo.apk
adb -s 015d4a826e43fb16 install foo.apk
adb -s 015d41d830240b11 install foo.apk
adb -s 015d2578a7280b02 install foo.apk
```